# How to Pass Current Taxonomy Terms into new WP_Query?

Tags: php, loop

On my single portfolio pages, I want to add a "See more from this category" section under the post.

Here is my code that checks for the single CPT and creates the new query:

```
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'bds_more_projects_query' );
    function bds_more_projects_query() {
        if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
            $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' );
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => array( $categories ),
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                echo the_title();
                endwhile;
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
    }
```

When I manually type in a term string, the appropriate titles all echo out as desired, but I cannot get the "get_the_terms" function to work for dynamic display of the current post category.

What am I missing is my code?

Comment: `terms` needs an array of term IDs, `get_the_terms` returns an array of term objects. Right now, your code places the array of term objects into another array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'bds_more_projects_query' );
function bds_more_projects_query() {
    if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
        $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category' );
        $cat_ids = array();
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            $cat_ids[] = $category->term_id;
        }
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( $cat_ids ),
                ),
            ),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            echo the_title();
            endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Basically, loop over the `$categories` array, adding the `term_id` of each to a new array, and then use that new array in the query arguments. The `get_the_terms` function returns an array of WP_Term objects, rather than just an array of IDs (see the [WP Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/#return) for more info).

The other thing to check is that `$post` is giving you the current post inside the function.

To verify, add `var_dump($post)` just inside the `is_singular( 'portfolio' )` condition and make sure it’s giving you the current post object. If it’s not, add `global $post` inside the `bds_more_projects_query` function and try again.

Comment: I verified that I was getting the current post, first by using the_title() and second by using var_dump($post). The var_dump can be seen here [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B72pZs-sUlzHRWZySl9GaENSeHM/view?usp=sharing). I did not see any info in there about my custom taxonomy. I thought it would be there. Problem?

After trying your code, I started getting error "Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array".

Comment: @danbru1989 Sorry…forgot that `get_the_terms` returns an array of objects, not an array of arrays. Changed line 7 of the sample code above and it should work correctly now.